# Is this activity-diagram showing well how my method works?

Tags: c#, uml

Is this activity-diagram showing well how my method works by first checking if the input is valid, if it isn't throw an exception, if it is: create 4 objects containing lists?

[image]
Not quite sure if activity diagrams are meant for this? Im trying to illustrate this:

```
public void MyMethod(string fileName) {
    if (condition) {
        var file = ReadFile("Levels", fileName);

        object1 = new object1();
        object1.Parse(file);

        object2 = new object2();
        object2.Parse(file);

        object3 = new object3();
        object3.Parse(file);

        object4 = new object4();
        object4.Parse(file);
    } else {
        throw new ArgumentException("Parser cannot load");
    }
}
```

I'm new to UML. Not sure if the activity diagram is valid this way and if it even makes sense to others.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid UML activity diagram. There are a number of ways to get a valid diagram. Personally, I would make the following changes:

1. Put `yes` and `no` in square brackets: `[yes]` and `[no]`.
2. Reverse the direction of the flow connected to `Throw exception`.
3. Add a so-called activity final node (a circle with a bullet inside) behind `Throw exception` and add a flow from `Throw exception` to the final node.
4. Remove the green part of your diagram completely and replace it with an action `Let every object parse itself`.
5. Add an activity final node below `Let every object parse itself` and add a flow from `Let every object parse itself` to the final node.